# Continuous function proof by definition

Tags: real-analysis, functions, continuity

> Prove that if $f$ is defined for $x\ge 0$ by $f(x)=\sqrt x$, then $f$
>   is continuous at every point of its domain.

Definition of a continuous function is:

Let $A\subseteq\mathbb{R}$ and let $f:A\to\mathbb{R}$. Denote $c\in A$.

Then $f(x)$ is continuous at $c$ iff for every $\varepsilon>0$, $\exists$ $\delta>0$ such that

$|x-c|<\delta\implies |f(x)-f(c)|<\varepsilon.$

My attempt:

We know that the function $f: x\to \mathbb{R}$, where $x\in [0,\infty)$ is defined to be $f(x)=\sqrt x$. So, for $0\le x<\infty$, then 
$|f(x)-f(c)|=|\sqrt x - f(c)|$ and I can't continue since I don't necessarily know what $c$ is in this case.

Comment: these types of proofs require that *you produce* a $\delta$ that will guarantee that $|f(x)-f(c)|<\epsilon$ (this $\delta$ is often dependent on $\epsilon$ and $c$)

Comment: @Coffee_Table But what or how do you find $c$ in this case? Is it just an arbitary number that must be greater than $0$?

Comment: The goal in an $\varepsilon-\delta$ proof such as this is to determine a value of $\delta$ in terms of $\varepsilon$.  How close to $c$ does $x$ need to be in order to guarantee that $f(x)$ is close enough to $f(c)$?

Comment: @SammyBlack Is it as close as $\sqrt x$?

Comment: Note that, $f$ is continuous from the right at $x=0$.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let us go from the definition you gave:

$f(x)$ is continuous at $c$ iff for every $\varepsilon>0$, $\exists$ $\delta>0$ such that

$|x-c|<\delta\implies |f(x)-f(c)|<\varepsilon.$

Given  $\varepsilon > 0$ we must show that $\vert \sqrt x - \sqrt c \vert < \varepsilon$  provided that $x$ and $c$ are close enough.

$$\vert \sqrt x - \sqrt c \vert = \frac {\vert x - c \vert} {\vert \sqrt x + \sqrt c \vert} < \frac {\vert x - c \vert} {\sqrt c} $$
So, $\delta = \varepsilon \sqrt{c}$ will do.

As pointed out by Ian, the above argument fails for $c = 0$. For $c = 0$, given $\varepsilon >0$, $\delta = \varepsilon^2$ would suffice.

Comment: Pondy, you chose $\sqrt c$ because it must be close to $\sqrt x$?

Comment: @Q.matin because by definition $f(c)=\sqrt c$, he didn't choose that. the part he chose was the $\delta$.

Comment: He's just showing you how $|x-c| < \epsilon $ if you choose $x$ within $\dfrac{\epsilon}{c}$ of $c$

Comment: @Coffee_Table Omg, wow, of course it is! I sometimes have too many brain lapse. Thanks!

Comment: @Q.matin: The definition says when ever $x$ and $c$ close enough($\delta$), $f(x)$ and $f(c)$ should be within $\varepsilon$. You don't choose $\sqrt c$ close to $\sqrt x$. You choose a $x$ that is close to $c$.

Comment: Understand, thanks guys for clearing this up!

Comment: In fact, $\delta = \varepsilon \cdot \sqrt{c}$ is what you want.

Comment: @pondy One last question: When you used $$\vert \sqrt x - \sqrt c \vert = \frac {\vert x - c \vert} {\vert \sqrt x + \sqrt c \vert} < \frac {\vert x - c \vert} {\sqrt c}$$ why did you get it only $\frac {\vert x - c \vert} {\sqrt c}$ where did the $\sqrt x$ in the denominator go?

Comment: @Q.matin: The objective was to get a delta independent of $x$.

Comment: @pondy And you used the triangle inequality to obtain that?

Comment: Note that, $\delta = \min\left\{c,\epsilon \sqrt{c}\right\} $.

Comment: and what if you are asked to show that the square root function is continuous at the point $c=0$ ? then both answers provided here are wrong. that is, $\delta_1 = \epsilon \sqrt{c}$, $\delta_2 = \min \lbrace c, \epsilon \sqrt{c} \rbrace$ and $\delta_3 = \epsilon / \sqrt{c}$ will not work for $c = 0$, we have $\delta_1$ and $\delta_2$ to not only prove nothing, but they are less than useless choices: they say nothing about continuity, and $\delta_3$ is an awful choice as you are in the bizarre world that your restriction is infinite. there is no such thing as infinite restriction. down-voted

Comment: This answer is not quite right. You have to handle this differently at $c=0$ and elsewhere. At $c \neq 0$, $|\sqrt{x}-\sqrt{c}|<\varepsilon$ if $|x-c|<\varepsilon \sqrt{c}$, as in the answer. At $c = 0$ we need $\delta > 0$ so that for $x < \delta$, $\sqrt{x} < \varepsilon$, which is given with $\delta = \varepsilon^2$.

Comment: Shouldn't it be $\delta = \varepsilon \sqrt{c}$ to get $|\sqrt{x}-\sqrt{a}|<\varepsilon$?

Comment: @Q.matin No triangle inequality needed. Since $|x-c| = |(\sqrt{x} - \sqrt{c})(\sqrt{x} + \sqrt{c})|,$ you can re-write $|\sqrt{x} - \sqrt{c}|$ as $\frac{x-c}{|\sqrt{x} + \sqrt{c}|}.$ Since $\sqrt{x}$ is a positive number, $  \frac{x-c}{|\sqrt{x} + \sqrt{c}|} < \frac{x-c}{\sqrt{c}}.$ The denominator $\sqrt{c}$ is smaller than the previous denominator $|\sqrt{x} + \sqrt{c}|$, so the whole quotient is larger.

Answer (score 2):

The answer above is not an answer. Try to show that the square root function is continuous at the point $c=0$ for the "choices" of $\delta$ given above and see the bizarre world that you end up in. More frustratingly, the people giving the answers make bigger mistakes or have bigger confusions about continuity than the person asking for continuity: for a detailed explanation on how to show that the square root function is continuous, here is a Pdf file that gives a detailed example. [LINK](http://www.math.caltech.edu/~2012-13/1term/ma001a/Continuous%20functions%20-%20expanded.pdf)

Answer (score 2):

user62089's answer is not quite right. At $c \neq 0$, user62089's work proves that $\delta = \varepsilon \sqrt{c}$ is sufficient. At $c=0$ you have a slightly different situation: you want $\delta>0$ so that $\sqrt{x}<\varepsilon$ for $x<\delta$. $\delta=\varepsilon^2$ works for this purpose.