# Open subset of $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$ proof

Tags: real-analysis

> Let $G\subset \mathbb{R}^n$ be open and $f:G\to \mathbb{R}$ be
>   continuous on $G$. Show that the set $$\{(a,b)\in\mathbb{R}^{n+1}:a\in
>  G,b>f(a)\}$$ is an open subset of $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$.

How can I prove this? I don't even know where to start.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Step 1:** the function $g:(a,b)\longmapsto b-f(a)$ is continuous on $G\times \mathbb{R}$. So your set $S=g^{-1}((0,+\infty))$ is open in $G\times \mathbb{R}$.

**Step 2:** since $G$ is open, $G\times\mathbb{R}$ is open in $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$.

**Step 3:** if $U$ is open in a topological space $X$, then $V\subseteq U$ is open in $U$ for the induced topology (that is $V=U\cap W$ for some open set $W$ in $X$) if and only if $V$ is open in $X$.

**Conclusion:** since $S$ in open in $G\times \mathbb{R}$ (step 1) which is open in $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$ (step 2), it is open in $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$ (step 3). The short argument once we have clarified all this is:
$$
S=g^{-1}((0,+\infty))=(G\times\mathbb{R})\cap W
$$
for some $W$ open in $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$.

**Note:** It might be interesting to see that, although tempting given the strict inequality defining $S$, the proof that the complement is closed is not necessarily easier in this situation. So I added it below.

**Complement argument:** consider the complement of your set
$$
S^c=G^c\times\mathbb{R}\cup\{(a,b)\;;\;a\in G\; b\leq g(a)\}.
$$
Since $G^c$ is closed the lhs is clearly closed. Now let $(a,b)$ be a limit point of $S^c$. It is either a limit point of the lhs or the rhs , or both. If it is a limit point of the lhs, it belong to it as we have just seen it is closed. Now if it is a limit point of the rhs, there are two cases to consider. First $a\not\in G$, then $(a,b)$ belongs to the lhs. Second, $a\in G$. Then $b\leq g(a)$ by continuity of $g$ at $a$ (as we have $(a_n,b_n)$ tending to $(a,b)$ with $a_n$ converging to $a$ in $G$ and $b_n\leq f(a_n)$ for all $n$, which yields $b\leq f(a)$ at the limit). So again $(a,b)$ belongs to $S^c$. So $S^c$ contains all its limit points. Hence it is closed and $S$ is open.

Comment: To be honest, I have no idea. Can you elaborate further?

Comment: @Q.matin I have given more steps. How is it now?

Comment: Julien: maybe it is easier to show that the complement of such set is closed simply by showing that it contains all it's limit points: we may use the criterion of sequential continuity in this metric space. Since $f(a)\geq b$ is a weak inequality, the proof would be almost immediate, for if $\lim x_n=\ell$ and $f(x_n)\geq b$, $\lim f(x_n)=f(\ell)\geq b$. We can illustrate this with the graph of a continuous function on the plane: it is simple a "twisted" version of the upper open half plane, so it is open.

Comment: @PeterTamaroff Yes, I thought that too. But the complement is $G^c\times \mathbb{R}\cup\{(a,b)\;;\;a\in G\; b\leq f(a)\}$. The lhs is easily closed. There is subtlety when handling the limit points of the rhs. They may leave it and fall in the lhs. Given the time it takes to explain this, it is almost as long as the open argument.

Comment: @PeterTamaroff I've written the complement argument. I think the direct open argument wins. What do you think?

Comment: @julien I think the open argument is tidier, but the closed argument might be more intuitive and helpful for the OP. Usually analysis courses start off with $\Bbb R^n$ viewed exclusively as a metric space and don't consider other spaces. Thus, things such as the product or relative topology might be alien. Consider the OP asked questions like [this one](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/339289/continuous-function-proof-by-definition) not too many days ago.

Comment: @PeterTamaroff The really easy question would have been: if $G$ is closed, then show $\{(a,b)\;;\;b\geq f(a)\}$ is closed. No need to worry about induced topology, plain sequences do the trick.

Comment: @julien Yup, that is wonderful!Thanks a lot! And Peter is correct in saying that first argument is alien to me because the second argument you stated was much more easily understandable to me. For example, I dont know how you got $g:(a,b)\longmapsto b-f(a)$, $S=g^{-1}((0,+\infty))$ and also $G\times\mathbb{R}$ is open in $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$.

Comment: @PeterTamaroff You read my mind again. If your not yet a professor, then you should strongly consider in being one! Thanks!

Comment: @Q.matin The notation $g^{-1}((0,+\infty))$ means the set of all $(a,b)$ in $G\times\mathbb{R}$ such that $g(a,b)>0\;\iff\;b>f(a)$. This is indeed your set $S$. Now $g$ is ocntinuous, so the inverse image of the open set $(0,+\infty)$ is open. That's step $1$. Regarding $G\times \mathbb{R}$, maybe you'll find it easier again to see that its complement $G^c\times \mathbb{R}$ is closed with sequences.

Comment: @julien Thanks for clearing that up! Last question, why would showing that the inverse image of the open set is open $(0,+\infty)$ be necessary/important in this case?

Comment: The real definition of continuity is: the inverse image of every open set is open. So when you're trying to prove something is open, it is natural to try to express it as the inverse image of some open set by some continuous functions.