# Proving a Function is continuous on an interval.

Tags: functions, continuity

For the function $f(x) = \frac {1}{\sqrt{x}}$ 
Show the function is continuous on (0, $\infty$)

How do I approach/do this question?

Comment: Did you try to use the definition of continuity?

Comment: An idea: prove $\;\sqrt x\;$ is continuous in $\;(0,\infty)\;$ and it doesn't vanish anywhere there, so your function is now continuous where you want since it is a quotient of two continuous functions with non-vanishing denomiantor.

Answer (score 1):

Let $A\subseteq\mathbb{R}$ and let $f:A\to\mathbb{R}$. Let $c\in A$.

Then $f(x)$ is continuous at $c$ iff for every $\varepsilon>0$, $\exists$ $\delta>0$ such that

$|x-c|<\delta\implies |f(x)-f(c)|<\varepsilon.$

In your case, $f(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}$ ,

So $|f(x)-f(c)| = |\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}} - \frac{1}{\sqrt{c}}|$

Try to prove that this value is bounded , given $|x-c|<\delta$.

Here is a similar problem : [Continuous function proof by definition](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/339289/continuous-function-proof-by-definition)

Answer (score 0):

Try following this:

$ f(x) $ is continuous on interval $ (a,b) $

if

$$ \lim\limits_{x \rightarrow a^{+}} f(x) = f(a) $$

and

$$ \lim\limits_{x \rightarrow b^{-}} f(x) = f(b) $$

It is also important to note that if $f$ is differentiable on some interval $(a,b)$ then $f$ is continuous on that interval.